# Printing the names of top 10 features and their chi square value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have a classification problem. I built a set of features for the data . I used SVM to classify . I want to evaluate the features.

```
ch2=SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k='all')
top_ranked_features = sorted(enumerate(ch2.scores_),key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:1000]
top_ranked_features_indices = map(list,zip(*top_ranked_features))[0]
for feature_pvalue in zip(np.asarray(featurenames)[top_ranked_features_indices],ch2.pvalues_[top_ranked_features_indices]):
       print feature_pvalue
```

But when I run this I got the following error

> AttributeError: 'SelectKBest' object has no attribute 'scores_'

Note: I haven't used vectorizer. I have the names of features in a list names `featurenames`  and I want to print the names and chi square values of all or top K features

Answer (score 1):

You only declared what scoring function you would like to use and the number of features to select. However, feature selection need **data** to find the best features using some statistical tests and afterwards you are able to access the scores. Here is an example, where `X` contains features and `Y` contains target values.

```
ch2= SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k='all').fit_transform(X, Y)
print(ch2.scores_)
```